# Python Boolean returning empty

Tags: python, boolean, return

why is this code not doing what i want it to do?
i want a simple True\False output but it keeps returning empty no matter how i write it.
what am i doing wrong here??

tried:

```py
yes = "True"
no = "False"

def check_up(num):
  if num == 2:
    return f"yes {yes}"  
  else:
    return f"something {no}"
    
num = int(input("please enter a number: "))
```

and also:

```py
def check_up(num):
  if num == 2:
    return True  
  else:
    return False
 
num = int(input("please enter a number: "))
```

simple True\False output.

Comment: where do you call `check_up`? Where do you output anything?

Comment: What is the function `check_up(num)`? You have defined it, but never call it.

Comment: You'll need to call *check_up()* and do something with its return value. *print()* maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the `check_up` method and print the result.

You can also simplify the `check_up` method.

```py
def check_up(num):
    return num == 2

num = int(input("Please enter a number:\n")
result = check_up(num)
print(result).
```

Or even simpler:

```py
num = int(input("Please enter a number:\n"))
print(num == 2)
```

This code will print `True` if the user inputs `2` and `False` if any other integer is inputted. If the input cannot be parsed as an integer an except will be thrown.

### Edit

Like DarkNight said; an exception will be thrown if the inputted string cannot be parsed as an integer.

Comment: And if the user enters BANANA you'll get an Exception. Probably ought to deal with that